# Objective-C variable release early when using Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to port an Objective-c program using mailcore2 to Swift. The code works fine in Objective-C but the closure code for the MCOSMTPSendOperation Start function never receive control and the sendOperationWithData is dealloc premature. It looks like the Start function is triggering the dealloc - not sure why. This doesn't happen in Objective-C.

```
func sendEmailMessage() {
    var smtpSession:MCOSMTPSession  = MCOSMTPSession()
    smtpSession.hostname = "smtp.comcast.net";
    smtpSession.port = 465;
    smtpSession.username = usernamet";
    smtpSession.password = "password";
    smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.TLS;

    var builder:MCOMessageBuilder = MCOMessageBuilder();
    var myto = ["to-emailt"]

    builder.header.from = MCOAddress(mailbox: "from-email");
    builder.header.to = myto;
    builder.header.replyTo = ["reply-email"];
    builder.header.subject = mySubject.text;
    builder.htmlBody = myBody.text;
    let rfc822Data:NSData = builder.data();

    println("doing send")
    var sendop:MCOSMTPSendOperation = smtpSession.sendOperationWithData(rfc822Data)

    sendop.start({ (error: NSError!) -> Void
        in
        println("Message sent successfully")
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`sendop` is deallocated when `sendEmailMessage()` returns, because there are no more strong references to it.

You need to either create a strong reference to it (a property) or store it somewhere that will do so. If `MCOSMTPSendOperation` is an `NSOperation` subclass, you could put it in an `NSOperationQueue` instead of calling `start()`. You could also add it to an array.